# Prevent Autoincrement on Duplicate Key Update

Tags: mysql, perl

I am using the following query to populate a database and return the Last Insert ID or the ID if the record exists already.  It works fine within my Perl script, however I am noticing that the auto increment field still goes up even if the the record exists which is causing gaps in the ID field.  Is there away around this?  I have looked at other examples but the query is not quite the same.

```
INSERT INTO `testTable` (`testA`, `testB`) VALES ("test1", "test2")
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Id` = LAST_INSERT_ID(`Id`);
```

Which is Perl I pick up the Id with :

```
$dbh->do($sql);
$blockInfo = $dbh->{mysql_insertid};
```

Thanks for your help or suggestions.  I thought about just doing an if statement which looks for the field and returns the Id if it is there and if not insert but I am trying to minimize the amount of queries I use.

Comment: Can you include more details?  If 'Id' is your auto-incremented column in 'testTable' why would you be changing it with the update?

Comment: It's a work around which returns the ID of the row if it already exists and will also return the ID if it just then had to insert it.  I decided to abandon this method and went directly to just running a query and if it returned nothing it would then just do an insert.  Much easier.  Thanks for responding.